# Always blank screen appearing after typing "amplify console", appsync page doesn't appear

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

When I enter amplify console from react native terminal by typing `amplify console`, just blank page appears. I don't see the overview of the appsync. When I look at console, `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` lines with no description in google chrome browser. I tried different combinations for adding api but results don't change, always blank screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, what worked for me was going private on chrome. Now I'm able to access the amplify console.